# How to refresh a RecylcerView?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview, data-class

I need to develop an app from university.

When I start the app, the RecyclerView is displayed correctly. However, when I refresh the RecyclerView or switch to another TAP, the card layouts are no longer displayed.

I get all the events from Firebase using an Event data class and pass them to the RecyclerAdapter.

Can you help me so that the refresh works?

Thanks a lot

Augustin

RecyclerAdapter:

```
class RecyclerAdapter(val events: List<Event>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

private lateinit var navController: NavController
private lateinit var events_id : String

var countEventId = mutableListOf<String>()
var count = 0

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view =
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.view_cardlayout, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount() = events.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(events[position])
}

inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun bind(event: Event) {
        itemView.headlineTV.text = event.name
        itemView.placeHolderTV.text = event.location
        itemView.dateHolderTV.text = event.date
        itemView.timeHolderTV.text = "${event.starttime} Uhr"
        itemView.dataHolderVotes.text = event.votes.toString()
        itemView.dataHolderVotes.text = event.votesUser?.size.toString()

        countEventId.add(event.eventId)
        count++
    }

    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val pos: Int =
                bindingAdapterPosition

            navController = findNavController(itemView)

            val action_HomeToData1 =
             HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToData1Fragment(countEventId[pos])
            navController.navigate(action_HomeToData1)
        }
    }
}
```

}

HomeFragment:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_home) {

private lateinit var firestoneDb: FirebaseFirestore
private lateinit var events: MutableList<Event>
//private lateinit var adapter: RecyclerAdapter


private var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    var auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    var user = auth.currentUser
    var uid = user?.uid


    firestoneDb = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    events = mutableListOf()

    recyclerView.adapter = RecyclerAdapter(events)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)


    val eventsReference = firestoneDb.collection("events")
    eventsReference
        .whereEqualTo("creator", uid)
        .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->
            if (exception != null || snapshot == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception when querying events", exception)
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }

            var eventList = snapshot.toObjects(Event::class.java)
            events.clear()
            events.addAll(eventList)

            for (event in eventList) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Event ${event}")
            }
        }

    refreshHome()

}


override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
}


private fun refreshHome() {

    refresherHome.setOnRefreshListener {

        Toast.makeText(activity, "Page has been refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        refresherHome.isRefreshing = false

        val action_HomeToSelf = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentSelf()
        findNavController().navigate(action_HomeToSelf)


    }
}
```

}

Data class Event:

```
data class Event (
var description: String = "",
@get: PropertyName("start_time") @set:PropertyName("start_time") var starttime: String = "",
var creator: String = "",
@get: PropertyName("event_id") @set:PropertyName("event_id")var eventId: String = "",
var location: String = "",
var name: String = "",
var questions: List<String>? = null,
var date: String = "",
@get: PropertyName("votes") @set:PropertyName("votes") var votes: Int = 0,
@get: PropertyName("creationTimeMs") @set:PropertyName("creationTimeMs")var creationTimeMs: Long = 0,
@get: PropertyName("votes_user") @set:PropertyName("votes_user")var votesUser: List<String>? = null
```

)

Answer (score 2):

After you change the events in the list, you need to tell the adapter that its data has change so that it knows to refresh the view. To do this call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, inside the snapshot listener after you're done modifying `events`.